# This code causes Corona to become unresponsive

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When I run this code in Corona on Windows 7 it instantly crashes.  It works fine in ZeroBrane.  Any ideas why?

```
--Stopwatch--

local startTime

function start()

startTime = os.time()
 --Start the stop watch--
end

function secondsEllapsed()
  --Return the number of seconds since the stop watch was started--
  return os.time() - startTime
end

start()

while true do

-- Get the time ellapsed and convert it to hours, minutes and seconds
ellapsed = secondsEllapsed()
hours = math.floor(ellapsed / 3600)
minutes = math.floor((ellapsed - (hours * 3600)) / 60)
seconds = math.floor((ellapsed - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)))

-- Print the time ellapsed to the command line
print(hours .. 'h', minutes .. 'm', seconds .. 's')

  end
```

Comment: it wouldn't let you post because there was not enough explanation to make any sense of it. Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score -1):

It crashes probably because you run infinity loop.